# Too much recursion when updating state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this example, when I try to update the state during the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle callback, I get a `too much recursion` error. How should I be updating the state?

```
import React from 'react';

class NotesContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { listOfShoppingItems: [] };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    let newShoppingItems = this.calculateShoppingItems();
    this.setState({ listOfShoppingItems: newShoppingItems });
  }

  calculateShoppingItems() {
    let shoppingItemsCart = []

    if (this.props.milk < 3) {
      let value = "Buy some milk";
      shoppingItemsCart.push(value);
    }

    if (this.props.bread < 2) {
      let value = "Buy some bread";
      shoppingItemsCart.push(value);
    }

    if (this.props.fruit < 10) {
      let value = "Buy some fruit";
      shoppingItemsCart.push(value);
    }

    if (this.props.juice < 2) {
      let value = "Buy some juice";
      shoppingItemsCart.push(value);
    }

    if (this.props.sweets < 5) {
      let value = "Buy some sweets";
      shoppingItemsCart.push(value);
    }

    return shoppingItemsCart;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Etc...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NotesContainer;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` is triggered when either the props or the state has changed. If you change the state in this method, you are causing an infinite loop (unless you implement `shouldComponentUpdate`).

It looks like your state changes when you receive new props, therefore `componentWillReceiveProps` seems a good place. From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops):

> Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before `render()` is called by updating the state using `this.setState()`. The old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling `this.setState()` within this function will not trigger an additional render.